# Github actions Deploy a stack to portainer

Tags: portainer

As in the documnetation [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGPXC.png)
even if changing the endpoint id the stack is getting deployed to the same local environment which has portainer server I want to deploy to the server containing portainer agent automatically

As in the documnetation [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGPXC.png)
even if changing the endpoint id the stack is getting deployed to the same local environment which has portainer server I want to deploy the stack to the server containing portainer agent automated for the CI/CD

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.